# Proper way of minifiying java script files in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

1. How can make sure that java script minification in wordpress does
   not create issues once it is done in theme development point of
   view?
2. Does wp-enqueque script order matter in minification process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ad1.** Just after make minification, do some tests with development tools (F12 in FF) There is a console where you will see all errors, warning etc. If something went wrong, you'll see it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console

---

**Ad2.** Hard to say because every case is different but sometimes it's matter.
Which plugin do you use for that? For example in W3 Total Cache you have an option which let you make order of your scripts for minification

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. some scripts may require jquery some may not(we specify it in wp enqueue as an array) .. won't it get effected? how does wp developer handles it?